# Как работать с PKCS7 и DES-CBC на Android?

Tags: android

У меня стоит задача дополнить сообщение до кратного 8 байтам размера с помощью алгоритма PKCS7, а затем кодируются алгоритмом DES-CBC с 8-байтовым ключом и инициализирующим массивом. Можете подсказать как лучше приступить к решению этой задачи? Я можно сказать в первый раз работаю с шифрованием, так что не так много знаю в этой области.

Comment: PKCS7 есть Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS как им можно что-то дополнить до 8 байт?! И в криптографии ничего дополнять не надо, там речь идёт о внутренних буферах и паддинге обычно. С точки зрения пользователя, вы даёте ему данные, а он возвращает зашифрованые данные, размером равным размеру блока шифрования *  на размер данных / размер блока шифрования + 1

Comment: @NewView, спасибо за подсказку, просто в ТЗ это именно так было сформулировано. А не знаете есть ли библиотеки для работы с шифрованием на android'e?